# Is it ok to have mapreudce input split size larger than container or tasktracker jvm heap size?

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

Normally, hadoop input split size defines number of mappers (containers) to handle the data.

For example, if a file is 2GB (block size 1GB, 2 blocks are used to store this file), the file will be stored in 2 HDFS blocks. But if I specify the input split size to be 2GB, 1 mapper will be assigned to process this file. If I do not specify the split size, then two mappers will be assigned (1 mapper for each block).

The question is -- what if my mapper jvm heap size is only 1GB while I use input split size as 2GB? Will my mapper JVM ran out of memory? Is it a good practice to always have input split size equal to or less than mapper jvm heap size?

Answer (score 1):

One input split would normally have more than one records. Your mapper only gets one record at a time. Hence as long as key or value contained in your record does not exceed your heap size limit you should be fine. Let us say if your value is a String/Text that exceeds heap size then you would certainly see OutOfMemory errors while mapper execution.